# Can not remove hyerlink underline with in line CSS for and Email Signature

Tags: css, hyperlink, inline, underline

I have created an email signature but I cannot get rid of the underline on hyperlinks when the client sends it from their mail client which is Outlook 2003. Yes, I know they should just upgrade as that is very old but they won't!
Does anyone have any ideas how to do it. I have searched on here and people have said to include things such as:

text-decoration:none !important

but this is not working! Is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: Consider adding `text-decoration:none;` for hover and active events.

Comment: I'd probably leave the underline in, you can understand that it's a link then. remove it, and I might not know where to click in the email.

Answer (score 1):

Some email clients will underlines links regardless of the CSS settings in the email.  Sometimes they don't even need to be links - if they look like a URL or an email address, many email clients will convert these to links and underline them automatically.

Comment: Agreed — outlook rewrites your HTML when you paste it in. Unfortunately, I have done a lot of testing and it always seems to underline; I think also that Outlook strips out `!important` too.

Comment: Thanks for everyones answers. It turned out that it was the clients mail server adding it after it was sent and there was no way around it.